# Pandas read_csv large file Performance improvement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-files

Just was wondering if there is a way to improve the performance of reading large csv files into a pandas dataframe. I have 3 large (3.5MM records each) pipe delimited file which I want to load into dataframe and perform some task on it. Currently I am using `pandas.read_csv()` defining the cols and there datatypes in the parameter like below. I did see some improvement by defining the datatype of the columns but it still takes more than 3 minutes to load.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, usecols = sourceFields, sep='|', header=0, dtype={'date':'str', 'gwTimeUtc':'str', 'asset':'|str', 
'instrumentId':'|str', 'askPrice':'float64', 'bidPrice':'float64', 
'askQuantity':'float64', 'bidQuantity':'float64', 'currency':'|str', 
'venue':'|str', 'owner':'|str', 'status':'|str', 'priceNotation':'|str', 'nominalQuantity':'float64'})
```

Comment: Check out `dask`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you wish to do with the data, a good option is [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). This library works out-of-memory, and allows you to perform a subset of `pandas` operations lazily. You can then bring the results in memory as a `pandas` dataframe. Below is example code you can try:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd, pandas as pd

# point to all files beginning with "file"
dask_df = dd.read_csv('file*.csv')

# define your calculations as you would in pandas
dask_df['col2'] = dask_df['col1'] * 2

# compute results & return to pandas
df = dask_df.compute()
```

Crucially, nothing significant is computed until the very last line.

Comment: `dask_df.compute()` *does* return a `pandas` dataframe, see [the docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). But, more importantly, try `type(df)` yourself.

Comment: I am not sure if dask DataFrame is going speed up the reading of the large files into the dataframe. I read the following on dask site "For data that fits into RAM, Pandas can often be faster and easier to use than Dask.dataframe". I tried using Dask.DataFrame and it did not improve the performance.

Comment: @RohitKhanna, agreed. What you will find is that if your memory is maxing out with `pd.read_csv()` then you have a chance with `dask`. It also works (ideal usage) when your computations include filtering by groups, thus minimizing the amount that needs to be brought into memory.

Answer (score 1):

The `.feather` file is significantly faster than `.csv`. Pandas has built-in support for feather files.

Read the csv in using `pd.read_csv(path)` and then export it to a feather file: `pd.to_feather(path)`. Now, read the feather file instead of csv.

In my case, a 950 MB csv file was compressed to a 180 MB feather file. Instead of taking 30 seconds to read, it takes about 1 second. I know I am a bit late to the party, but feather files are seriously underrated.